# Why am I seeing the _entities request in one service when the entity is native to another?

Tags: apollo-federation

I'm working on implementing services compatible with Apollo GraphQL federation; my providing services are written in Lacinia (GraphQL library for Clojure).

I have one service that defines Users:

```
type User @key(fields: "id") {
  id: String!
  name: String!
}

type Query {
  user_by_id(id:String!) : User
}

schema { query: Query }
```

and and a second that defines Products and extends Users:

```
type User @extends @key(fields: "id") {
  id: String! @external
  favorite_products: [Product]
}

type Product @key(fields: "upc") {
  upc: String!
  name: String!
  price: Int!
}

type Query {
    product_by_upc(upc: String!) : Product
}

schema { query: Query }
```

When I execute a query that spans services:

```
{
  user_by_id(id: "me") {
    id
    name
    favorite_products {
      upc
      name
      price
    }
  }
}
```

I get a failure; the following request is sent to the `products` service:

```
INFO  products.server - {:query "query($representations:[_Any!]!){_entities(representations:$representations){...on User{favorite_products{upc name price}}}}", :vars {:representations [{:__typename "User", :id "me"}]}, :line 52}
```

and that fails, because the products service shouldn't, as far as I know, have to provide the equivalent of `__resolveReference` for type `User` (which it extends); just type `Product`.

This is very unclear in the documentation and I'll experiment with providing a kind of stub reference resolver in Product for stubs of User.

Comment: Ok, I can now see that the products service does have to implement a kind of stub for the `User`, and that does make sense.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed, you must provide the `__resolveReference` (or equivalent) for each type the service schema extends.  In retrospect, it makes sense, as it provides the "kernel" of a raw value to be passed down the resolver tree.